# Lining up output in linux cli

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I have a tool which outputs four columns of data with a space between each. However, the data items are variable length, and it's hard to read what's going on.

Is there a way I can line the output up using linux utilities to tabulate it for easy reading?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
cat $DataFile | column -t
```

in debian column is in package [bsdmainutils](http://packages.debian.org/bsdmainutils). and of course you can also use `column -t $DataFile`